# How can I have multiple jQuery button styles on one page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm using the following external CSS files:

```
<link href="/jquery_custom/green/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/jquery_custom/css/blue/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /></script>
```

And JavaScript:

```
<script language = "javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").button();
    }); 
</script>
```

I have noticed on the jQuery UI site there is an Advanced option:

[image: jQuery site Advanced options]

What do I need to do to have more than one style one the page? Including the two separate external ui-custom js files cause problems. And I notice Facebook has two different colored buttons:

[image: Facebook homepage with two different colored buttons]

How can this be done?

Comment: Could you wrap those links in markdown link tags and provide a link text? Kind of bulks-up your question w/o a good reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean have different colors/styles for each button? You can do that with just CSS, like so:

**CSS**

```
a.button {
    color: #6e6e6e;
    font: bold 12px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 7px 12px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,0% 40%,0% 70%,from(#F5F5F5),to(#F1F1F1));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(linear,0% 40%,0% 70%,from(#F5F5F5),to(#F1F1F1));
    border: solid 1px #dcdcdc;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}


a.red {
    color:#fff;
    background: red;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,0% 40%,0% 70%,from(#FF0000),to(#F1F1F1));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(linear,0% 40%,0% 70%,from(#FF0000),to(#F1F1F1));
}

a.green {
    background: #7FFF24;
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear,0% 40%,0% 70%,from(#7FFF24),to(#F1F1F1));
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(linear,0% 40%,0% 70%,from(#7FFF24),to(#F1F1F1));
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="button">Gray Button</a>
<a href="#" class="button red">Red Button</a>
<a href="#" class="button green">Green Button</a>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/cXv8A/)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but it should be the same principle even across themes.

Comment: I agree with Andres, just give the buttons some kind of class and make a css rule for it. Make sure it gets executed after the jqueryUI css stuff (just stick the external css lower in the list).

Comment: @tjameson my point exactly. If i understand correctly what you want to do is add multiple themes to your page, why not just use the Theme Roller and create just one sheet and be done with it? Adding multiple theme sheets can cause more headaches than its worth. Either that, or just copy over the styles that you are looking for and create a special class for the button you want styled differently, like in my demo above, that is by far the cleanest way you can go about it.

Comment: I don't understand, how can this solve the problem of the "Upgrade Account" button not being green?

Comment: As @tjameson pointed out, there is an image acting as a background for the button, so you can overwrite that with a css color, but you could overwrite the style through another class like so:

Comment: button.green {
  background-color: #A1C820;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#A1C820), to(#7FA81B));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #A1C820, #7FA81B);
  background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #A1C820, #7FA81B);
  background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #A1C820, #7FA81B);
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #A1C820, #7FA81B);
  background-image:         linear-gradient(top, #A1C820, #7FA81B);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#A1C820', EndColorStr='#7FA81B');
}

Comment: Then just add that class to the button, as in: <button class="greenfc green ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Upgrade Account</span></button>

Answer (score 0):

The javascript you posted doesn't create the button UI, it just handles the click event, so not sure why that is important here. Whether you've added the `<input type="button" />` elements in html or generated them in javascript - either way just use class or id identifiers and modify the look of the buttons in your own css.

The jquery ui css theme is vital to the operation of some complex ui controls, such as the date picker, but for a simple button, I would view the jquery css as a solid starting point for your modifications. Include your css file after the jquery ui one, so you can modify just the styles you need, and no more.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since you've clarified, check out:
[Using Multiple jQuery Themes in a single page](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/using_multiple_jquery_ui_themes_on_a_single_page/)
You can tell each theme to apply only to a specific portion of the page.

Comment: I just used fiddler on the page, and from what I can tell, the green css stylesheet isn't loading. It appears to be using @import to 2 other parts of the stylesheet, and they fail to load.